Broadcast Channel API is not working in Private Tab in safari
I am trying to use BroadcastChannel API in Safari. onMessage event is firing in normal mode as expected. But when I use private window,onMessage event is not firing. Does BroadcastChannel API have restrictions in usage in private window?
